# How to fetch path-parameters from the requested resource URI in policies of Keycloak Authorization Services?

Tags: javascript, resources, authorization, keycloak, policy

With [Keycloak Authorization Services](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/) (Version 11.0), we want to implement the following rule (pathes and claims are only for demonstration):

> Allow the request to resource `/users/{username}/more/sub/pathes` if the value of the claim `username` in the access-token matches the value of the parameter `username` in the requested resource.

For example:

> Allow the request to resource `/users/alice/more/sub/pathes` if the claim `username` in the access-token has value `alice`.
>
> Allow the request to resource `/users/bob/more/sub/pathes` if the claim `username` in the access-token has value `bob`.

We are able to create our own policy with [JavaScript-Based Policies](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_policy_js). As shown in the [example](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#checking-for-attributes-from-the-current-identity), we can fetch any claim from the access-token (e.g. the desired `username` claim) and evaluate it in our JS code.

The questions are:

1. How can we define the path-parameters in the resource URI?
2. How can we fetch the path-parameters in the code of my JS policy?
3. If it is not possible to define path-parameters, how can we at least fetch the complete requested resource URI?

According to the [JavaDocs of the Policy Evaluation API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/11.0/javadocs/) (org.keycloak.authorization.policy.evaluation.Evaluation), we can fetch the `Resource` object. However, as far as we know, this object contains the resource as defined in Keycloak and not the requested resource, i.e. it contains the URI with the parameter `{username}` but not the concrete value of it.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Check this quickstart example, https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/app-authz-rest-employee
You can combine the js policy and get the path params in the keycloak server http://localhost:8080/api/{employee}

Comment: basically what you need is to integrate the Claim Information Point and resolve the claim from the request.uri, more info at https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_enforcer_claim_information_point

Comment: This seems exactly to be what I was looking for. I will have a closer look at this and test it out. Thanks for providing the link to the Keycloak Quickstarts, @kristianva

Answer (score 0):

Handing in method `org.keycloak.adapters.authorization.util.RequestPlaceHolderResolver.resolve(String placeHolder, HttpRequest request)`

```java
        ...
        else if (source.startsWith("method")) {
            String value = request.getMethod();

            if (value != null) {
                return Arrays.asList(value);
            }
        } else if (source.startsWith("uri")) {
            String value = request.getURI();

            if (value != null) {
                return Arrays.asList(value);
            }
        } else if (source.startsWith("relativePath")) {
            String value = request.getRelativePath();

            if (value != null) {
                return Arrays.asList(value);
            }
        }
        ...
```

Only the judgment `source.startsWith("uri")` is no processing support for the path variable, Override this method is a good choice.